# Cardinalidad en java

Tags: java

Buenas noches, mi duda es acerca de en este caso, como implementaría esto, "El empleado puede tener de 1 a 3 servicios", ¿como representaría eso en código? Esto es lo que tengo:

```
package Hojatrabajo;

public class Empleado {

    //ATRIBUTOS
    private String nombre;
    private String cedula;
    private String cargo; 
    private int anoIngreso;

    //RELACIONES
    private Servicio servicio1;
    private Servicio servicio2;
    private Servicio servicio3;

    //METODOS
    public Empleado(String nombre, String cedula, String cargo){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.cedula = cedula;
    }   

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getCedula() {
        return cedula;
    }

    public void setCedula(String cedula) {
        this.cedula = cedula;
    }

    public String getCargo() {
        return cargo;
    }

    public void setCargo(String cargo) {
        this.cargo = cargo;
    }

    public int getAnoIngreso() {
        return anoIngreso;
    }

    public void setAnoIngreso(int anoIngreso) {
        this.anoIngreso = anoIngreso;
    }

    public boolean agregarServicio(String){

    }

    public boolean eliminarServicio(String){

    }

    public boolean calcularCostoPromedioServicios(){
        boolean promedio = (servicio1.calcularIngresosMasImpuestos() + servicio2.calcularIngresosMasImpuestos() + servicio3.calcularIngresosMasImpuestos())/3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Por que no usas arreglos?

Comment: por el momento no se usar arreglos, y en este programa no podemos usar arreglos por reglas de la actividad

Answer (score -1):

La regla dice:

> El empleado puede tener de 1 a 3 servicios

Esto significa:

- El atributo debe soportar múltiples servicios (independiente al tamaño que es la limitante). Esto se traduce en que debes tener una estructura como arreglo, lista u otro.
- El atributo debe soportar **por lo menos 1 servicio**. Esto se traduce en que se debe solicitar por lo menos 1 servicio al momento de la construcción de la clase.

Conociendo estas dos condiciones a partir de la regla, podemos elaborar el diseño de nuestra clase (ignoro los demás campos para simplificar la respuesta):

```
public class Empleado {
    private List<String> listaServicios;

    public Empleado(String servicio) {
        //esta lista no permite agregar más elementos ni remover los elementos actuales
        listaServicios = Arrays.asList(servicio);
    }

    public Empleado(String servicio1, String servicio2) {
        listaServicios = Arrays.asList(servicio1, servicio2);
    }

    public Empleado(String servicio1, String servicio2, String servicio3) {
        listaServicios = Arrays.asList(servicio1, servicio2, servicio3);
    }

    public String getServicio(int indice) {
        if (indice <= 0 || indice >= listaServicios.size()) {
            return null;
        }
        return listaServicios.get(indice);
    }
}
```

Si necesitas diseñar la lista de manera mutable, es decir, que permita soportar más datos en el futuro, solo debes envolver el resultado de `Arrays.asList` dentro de un `ArrayList`. Ejemplo:

```
public Empleado(String servicio) {
    //esta lista sí permite agregar más elementos ni remover los elementos actuales
    listaServicios = new ArrayLists<>(Arrays.asList(servicio));
}
```

---

Si no puedes usar alguna colección, entonces solo te queda usar un diseño declarando las variables requeridas:

```
public class Empleado {

    private String servicio1;
    private String servicio2;
    private String servicio3;

    public Empleado(String servicio) {
        this(servicio, "", "");
    }

    public Empleado(String servicio1, String servicio2) {
        this(servicio1, servicio2, "");
    }

    public Empleado(String servicio1, String servicio2, String servicio3) {
        this.servicio1 = servicio1;
        this.servicio2 = servicio2;
        this.servicio3 = servicio3;
    }

    //getters y setters...
}
```